# How to jump back to main from a function?

Tags: c, function

I need to jump back to main from function create_task to main. I labeled where I want to jump to and from where.
is there logic for it or can we use a built-in function? goto statements aren't working. calling the main function stops the program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
struct task{
char t_name[99];
char task_noted[999];
};
void create_task(struct task *arrayt );
int main(){

struct task arrayt[999];
//i want to get here!!!
int check=0;
while(check>3||check<1){
    printf("Enter 1 to create a task\nEnter 2 to delete a task\nEnter 3 to veiw task:\n");
    scanf("%d",&check);
}

switch(check){
    case 1:
        printf("CREATING A TASK\n");
        create_task(arrayt);
        break;
    case 2:
        printf("DELETE TASK");
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("VEIW TASKS");
        break;
    default :
        printf("INVALID OPTION!!!!");
        break;
}
}
void create_task(struct task *arrayt ){
int i=0,want=0;
FILE *ptr;
while(i!=999){
    if(arrayt[i].t_name!= NULL && arrayt[i].task_noted!= NULL){
        
        ptr = fopen("data.txt","a");
        printf("Enter Task Name: ");
        scanf("\n%[^\n]s",arrayt[i].t_name);
        fprintf(ptr,"\n%s",arrayt[i].t_name);
        printf("\nEnter Task Data:\n");
        scanf("\n%[^\n]s",arrayt[i].task_noted);
        fprintf(ptr,"\n%s",arrayt[i].task_noted);
        i++;
        printf("\nDo you want to add another task?\nPRESS 1 FOR ANOTHER\nPRESS 2 TO EXIT\n");
        scanf("%d",&want);
        if(want==2){
            //i want to goto main from here!!!!
        }
        fclose(ptr);
        
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`return`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/return) statement, and not gotos or anything like that:

```
if (want == 2) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an if statement at the beggining of main with a bool set to false and when want is 2 set it to true.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to jump back to `main` from function `create_task` to `main`.

### Another possibility could be to *carefully* use [setjmp(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setjmp.3.html) with `longjmp`.

**Beware, they are confusing** (since `longjmp` is shrinking your [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)) **and might make your code unreadable**. Be sure to document and comment more your code. You may need to use [fflush(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) a bit more or to end your `printf` format control strings with a `\n`. See also [setvbuf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html).

#### As a rule of thumb, `longjmp` should be *rarely* used. It is some kind of [exception handling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) in C.

The difficult issue could be to "undo" important side effects (in particular, [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)) done between a `setjmp` and its corresponding `longjmp`. You'll need some good [code review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review) in that case.

---

> ```
>    ptr = fopen("data.txt","a");
> ```

Seems wrong (since in your code you forgot to test `ptr`). What would happen when [fopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) fails (this can happen when running your program in a different [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory))? Further calls to [fprintf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html) could crash. Beware of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

> ```
>     printf("DELETE TASK");
> ```

I recommend coding `printf("DELETE TASK\n");` which might avoid buffering and show that message earlier in your terminal.

A related concept is [continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) and [continuation passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) (in C, with [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming))).

Be sure to read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and look into [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) website (and later inside some C draft standard such as [n2176](https://files.lhmouse.com/standards/ISO%20C%20N2176.pdf)). Read also the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)). I suggest to compile your code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (all warnings and debug info), then to use GDB to understand its behavior. On Linux, you could also use [ltrace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/trace.1.html).

Comment: i know that i havent put a condition for testing ptr. i just want it to run smoothly, then i will add that. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: You’re a really good programmer.  You *know* that setjmp is using a sledgehammer to crack an egg, that the issue is organization rather than flow control.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are thinking about using the jumping statements like `goto`, `break`, and `continue` they won't help you to jump from one function to another. That is because the two functions have different scopes. You can use a `return statement` if you want the control to be returned to the `main()`.
- if you declare the function `void function (...)`, then you can simply return at any point, or allow control to run off the end of the function -- the compiler will automatically return to the calling function
- if you declare the function to return a value `int function(...)` then you must `return XXX`and `XXX` type must match the return type of the function

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not really that you want to “jump back” to `main`. What you want is to have a loop reading and processing user input. To do that, make a loop using a `while` statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Put needed declarations here.

    while (1)
    {
        // Prompt user and read input.
        printf("Enter 1 to create a task.\n...\nEnter 0 to stop.\n");
        int check;
        int result = scanf("%d", &check);

        // Test whether scanf worked.  End the program if it failed.
        if (result != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "scanf failed.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // If the user entered 0 to stop the loop, stop the loop.
        if (check == 0)
            break;

        // Dispatch based on the user's request.
        switch (check)
        {
            case 1:
                // Do stuff for case 1.
                break;
            case 2:
                // Do stuff for case 2.
                break;
            case 3:
                // Do stuff for case 3.
                break;

            // Handle incorrect input from user.
            default:
                printf("Error, %d is not a valid choice.\n", check);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```